# How to make meteor work on 64bit mongodb on windows 10?

Tags: windows, mongodb, meteor, 64-bit, windows-10

I just install meteor.js and try to use it replace the old frameworks.
The issue is:

On my windows 10 64bit system, the meteor is use 32bit mongodb(2.6.7), which is limited th database size is 2gb.

How to make the meteor work with 64bit mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having researched this myself just now, it looks as though the Meteor version 1.4 release will be updated to version 3.2 of MongoDB, in which "*32-bit binaries are deprecated*"

- [Github ticket for the updating of MongoDB](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6957)
- [MongoDB declaration that 3.2 has deprecated 32-bit binaries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/#deprecation-of-32-bit-versions)
- [Meteor 1.4 announcement](https://forums.meteor.com/t/coming-soon-meteor-1-4/23260)

If upgrading your MongoDB instance is mandatory **now**, then unfortunately it looks like the only way is to manually upgrade the binaries yourself. If you do this, I would suggest you make a backup of them just in-case it messes up.

To upgrade to version 3.2 you first need to [upgrade to version 3.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/), then you can [upgrade to version 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't install the right version of Mongo if you have a 32 bits version.

check out their installation guide:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

First download the right 64 bits version for Windows:
https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production

and follow the instructions:

> Install MongoDB
>
> Interactive Installation 1 Install MongoDB for Windows. In Windows
>   Explorer, locate the downloaded MongoDB .msi file, which typically is
>   located in the default Downloads folder. Double-click the .msi file. A
>   set of screens will appear to guide you through the installation
>   process.
>
> You may specify an installation directory if you choose the “Custom”
>   installation option.
>
> NOTE These instructions assume that you have installed MongoDB to
>   C:\mongodb. MongoDB is self-contained and does not have any other
>   system dependencies. You can run MongoDB from any folder you choose.
>   You may install MongoDB in any folder (e.g. D:\test\mongodb).

Comment: I already install the mongodb 64biit version, but the problem is still there. @MrE

Comment: I really doubt that the 64 bit version runs in 32 bits, so what makes you think it is?

Comment: @MrE Meteor ships with a version of MongoDB embedded within it (2.6.7 as of current date). If you download MongoDB separately it still doesn't use it so I'm afraid your answer isn't very helpful for this question.

Comment: @Jamie Barker: i have 2.6.6 and 2.6.7 versions running on my laptop and they are 64 bits. You can use MONGO_URL=<hostname:port> to point to your own mongo instance.